# How to change model variable by onclick function used in template asynchronously (without refreshing explicitly)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I am making a django app where the user can post status'. The list of his previous status' is also showed on the same page with a `delete post` option against each post. I have added an onclick function to that button which uses `ajax calls to change the class variable in models.py`. ie. the delete variable in class status_class in models.py changes its value from 0 to 1 after the delete post button is clicked. And then only the posts with delete=1 are showed. Help me `modify the delete_post function` in the script so that it works as I've mentioned above. Please do mention if any other changes are needed. Thanks.

### Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class status_class(models.Model):
    username=models.ForeignKey(User)
    text=models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=False, blank=False)
    pub_date=models.DateTimeField("Published: ")
    delete=models.IntegerField(default=0)

     def __unicode__(self):
        return self.text
```

### Script in template

```
<script>
    function deletepost(id)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/delete_post/",
            type: "POST",
            data: {'value':id},
            success: function(response) {
            },

        });
    }
</script>
```

### URL

```
url(r'^delete_post/$', 'status.views.deletepost_view', name='deletepost_view'),
```

### View

```
@csrf_exempt
def deletepost_view(request):
    value=request.POST.get("value")
    b=User.objects.filter(id=str(value))
    #delete change statement
    resp=json.dumps(b)
    return HttpResponse(resp, content_type="application/json")
```

### Template

```
{% for i in d %}
<p>{{ i.text }} &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp {{ i.pub_date }}
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deletepost(i.id);"> Delete Post </button></p>
<hr>

{% endfor %}
```

`NOTE:` Also help me with this. I want to filter posts and show only that posts having the delete variable equal to 0. ie. that have not been deleted. Where should I write the filter statement?

Comment: Since you didn't mention what is actually wrong with the code you've posted, we can't really help you fix it. As for filtering non-deleted posts, what about the very clear [filter documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) is confusing you?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have now specified my doubt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes to the following would work.

### View

```
def deletepost_view(request):

    value=request.POST.get("value")
    b=status_class.objects.get(id=str(value))
    b.delete = 1
    b.save()

    resp=json.dumps(b)

    return HttpResponse(resp, content_type="application/json")
```

### Template

```
{% for i in d %}
<p>{% if i.delete == 0  %}
      {{ i.text }}&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp {{ i.pub_date }}
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deletepost({{ i.id }});"> Delete Post </button>
      <hr></p>
   {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```